# WPF Combobox: Different result in textbox and drop-downlist

Tags: c#, wpf

I have a combox that I have data binded to a viewmodel.

The dropdown cells are displayed properly but the comboxbox textblock doesn't show the same.

[image]

This is my combobox xaml

```
<ComboBox x:Name="UserComboBox" ItemsSource="{Binding userInfoViewModel.Users}" 
       SelectedItem="{Binding userInfoViewModel.SelectedUser, Mode=TwoWay}"  
           ItemTemplate="{StaticResource UserTemplate}"
           ItemContainerStyle="{DynamicResource CustomUserComboBoxStyle}" 
           HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="39.025,217.76,0,186.025" Width="204.975" IsEditable="True" Background="#FFF3F3F3" 
           BorderBrush="{DynamicResource CustomBorder}" 
           Height="27.24" >
</ComboBox>
```

This is my UserTemplate

```
<DataTemplate x:Key="UserTemplate">
      <StackPanel FlowDirection="LeftToRight"  Orientation="Horizontal">
          <TextBlock Text="{Binding Path=InternalNumber}"></TextBlock>
          <TextBlock Text="{Binding Path=UserName}" ></TextBlock>
      </StackPanel>
</DataTemplate>
```

and my CustomUserComboBoxStyle

```
<Style x:Key="CustomUserComboBoxStyle" TargetType="{x:Type ComboBoxItem}">
        <Setter Property="HorizontalContentAlignment" Value="{Binding HorizontalContentAlignment, RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType={x:Type ItemsControl}}}"/>
        <Setter Property="VerticalContentAlignment" Value="{Binding VerticalContentAlignment, RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType={x:Type ItemsControl}}}"/>
        <Setter Property="Padding" Value="3,0,3,0"/>
        <Setter Property="Background" Value="Transparent"/>
        <Setter Property="Template">
            <Setter.Value>
                <ControlTemplate TargetType="{x:Type ComboBoxItem}">
                    <Border x:Name="Bd" BorderBrush="{TemplateBinding BorderBrush}" BorderThickness="{TemplateBinding BorderThickness}" 
                            Background="{TemplateBinding Background}" Padding="{TemplateBinding Padding}" SnapsToDevicePixels="true">
                            <ContentPresenter HorizontalAlignment="{TemplateBinding HorizontalContentAlignment}" 
                                          SnapsToDevicePixels="{TemplateBinding SnapsToDevicePixels}" 
                                          VerticalAlignment="{TemplateBinding VerticalContentAlignment}"/>
                    </Border>
                    <ControlTemplate.Triggers>
                        <Trigger Property="IsHighlighted" Value="true">
                            <Setter Property="Background" Value="#646363" />
                            <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="#FFFFFFFF"/>
                            <Setter Property="BorderBrush" Value="#646363"/>
                        </Trigger>
                        <Trigger Property="IsHighlighted" Value="false">
                            <Setter Property="Background" Value="#FFF3F3F3" />
                            <Setter Property="BorderBrush" Value="#FFF3F3F3"/>
                        </Trigger>
                        <Trigger Property="IsEnabled" Value="false">
                            <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="{DynamicResource {x:Static SystemColors.GrayTextBrushKey}}"/>
                        </Trigger>
                    </ControlTemplate.Triggers>
                </ControlTemplate>
            </Setter.Value>
        </Setter>
    </Style>
```

Why does the combobox show Digicom.Eventserver.Client.user instead of the name and number?

Answer (score 1):

Your simplest solution would be to override the `ToString()` method in your user data class:

```
public override string ToString()
{
    return string.Concat(InternalNumber, UserName);
}
```

Comment: This, and then you don't have to use a template at all.

Answer (score 0):

You could set the `ComboBox.DisplayMemberPath` property.

That property accepts the name of only one property of the DataContext object. If you want to use two properties (InternalNumber and Username) you should use a ValueConverter or (better way IMHO) a ViewModel class